# Большой трафик с собственного IP

Tags: php, joomla

Вопрос такой - сайт сделан на Joomla почему с моего же IP идёт сумасшедший трафик на сервер сайта? Вирусов у меня нет, проверено разными антивирусниками. Как-то раз было аж 18000 заходов на сервер сайта с моего IP. Что это такое может быть?

Сайт мой, работаю с админкой и с другого места, там макинтош и другой IP  и все равно большой трафик. Стоит пару тройку страниц сделать и уже тысячи заходов. И что, эта проблема не решается никак? Просто начинается превышение по нагрузке на процессор и мой сайт отключают до устранения проблем. Вот так.

Comment: 1.чей сайт, что за сайт, может ваш? 2.трафик, чем проверяли, если проверяли то вы достаточно знаете чтобы блокарнуть трафик или посмотреть что вы шлете серверу. 3.вирусы, существуют рекламные вирусы, они в обычных антивирусах так проскакивают, требуются спец антивирусы.

Comment: Сайт Ваш или нет? Вы сами ни какие манипуляции не делаете? Такое количество заходов может запросто сделать, например, сканер безопасности, при анализе, или парсер при заполнении интернет-магазина, или робот, проверяющий SEO показатели. Надо смотреть логи сервера, тогда все станет понятно.

Comment: Исследуйте запущенные процессы на предмет большой нагрузки на ЦПУ и большого сетевого трафика.